# How to resize a SVG element composed of multiple paths in JavaFX?

Tags: svg, javafx, javafx-8

I'm remaking the design of an old javafx app and I need to include an icon for the wifi strength. The designer sent me an svg icon for that, and I thought it was smarter to just keep one icon and use different fill colors for the 3 bars depending of the said wifi strength.

I found a nice approach for that, and it works quite well until you need to resize the wifi icon. It seems like even if I change the `-fx-pref-width` (or height, or min/max) the svg icon keeps its size.
I also tried to resize each svg path one by one but it only goes messy with the spaces between them. And using a unique shape to resize later is not an option, as I need at least 2 colors. FYI the goal is to apply a `5em` or `3em` size depending of the context.

Here's the code I currently have, where everything looks great if you don't matter the icon size :

```java
public class WifiStrengthRegion extends Pane {

    public WifiStrengthRegion() {
        getStyleClass().setAll("wifi-strength");

        SVGPath round = new SVGPath();
        SVGPath bar1 = new SVGPath();
        SVGPath bar2 = new SVGPath();
        SVGPath bar3 = new SVGPath();

        round.setContent("M253.5,336.5c-18.9,0-34.2,15.3-34.2,34.1c0,18.8,15.4,34.1,34.2,34.1c18.9,0,34.2-15.3,34.2-34.1 C287.7,351.8,272.4,336.5,253.5,336.5z");
        bar1.setContent("M337,290.1c-22.3-22.3-51.9-34.5-83.5-34.5c-31.4,0-61,12.2-83.3,34.3c-9,9-9,23.5,0,32.5 c4.4,4.4,10.2,6.8,16.3,6.8c6.2,0,11.9-2.4,16.3-6.7c13.6-13.5,31.6-20.9,50.7-20.9c19.2,0,37.3,7.5,50.8,21 c4.4,4.4,10.2,6.8,16.3,6.8c6.2,0,11.9-2.4,16.3-6.7C346,313.6,346,299,337,290.1z");
        bar2.setContent("M389.3,238c-36.3-36.2-84.5-56.1-135.8-56.1c-51.2,0-99.3,19.9-135.6,55.9c-4.4,4.3-6.8,10.1-6.8,16.3 c0,6.1,2.4,11.9,6.7,16.3c4.4,4.3,10.2,6.7,16.3,6.7c6.2,0,11.9-2.4,16.3-6.7c27.5-27.4,64.1-42.5,103-42.5 c39,0,75.6,15.1,103.1,42.6c4.4,4.4,10.2,6.8,16.3,6.8c6.2,0,12-2.4,16.3-6.7c4.4-4.3,6.8-10.1,6.8-16.3 C396,248.1,393.6,242.3,389.3,238z");
        bar3.setContent("M444.3,183.2c-50.9-50.8-118.7-78.8-190.8-78.8c-72,0-139.7,27.9-190.6,78.6c-9,9-9,23.5,0,32.5 c4.4,4.3,10.2,6.7,16.3,6.7c6.2,0,12-2.4,16.3-6.7c42.2-42,98.3-65.2,158-65.2c59.7,0,115.9,23.2,158.1,65.3 c4.4,4.3,10.2,6.7,16.3,6.7c6.2,0,11.9-2.4,16.3-6.7C453.2,206.7,453.3,192.1,444.3,183.2z");

        round.getStyleClass().add("wifi-base");
        bar1.getStyleClass().add("wifi-bar1");
        bar2.getStyleClass().add("wifi-bar2");
        bar3.getStyleClass().add("wifi-bar3");

        this.getChildren().addAll(round, bar1, bar2, bar3);
    }

    public void setWifiStrength(Integer strength) {
        if (strength == null) {
            setManaged(false);
            setVisible(false);
        } else {
            setManaged(true);
            setVisible(true);
            getStyleClass().removeAll("wifi-excellent", "wifi-good", "wifi-fair", "wifi-weak", "wifi-off");

            if (strength < 0 && strength >= -100) {
                if (strength >= -50) {
                    getStyleClass().add("wifi-excellent");
                } else if (strength >= -70) {
                    getStyleClass().add("wifi-good");
                } else if (strength >= -80) {
                    getStyleClass().add("wifi-fair");
                } else {
                    getStyleClass().add("wifi-weak");
                }
            } else {
                getStyleClass().add("wifi-off");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

(and then a css stylesheet applies `-fx-fill` to each .wifi-barX depending of the main element class)

And here is an example of how the svg icon looks like:
<kbd>[image: svg icon]</kbd>

I'm a very beginner in Java (and obv JavaFX), so any constructive criticism will be appreciated!

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Yeah sure, what more would you want? The java class is all here, I only didn't put the imports. The CSS is pretty much already described, but it it really helps I can include it as well. And the minimal FXML needed is basically `<WifiStrengthRegion />`. Pls tell me if I missed something :/

Comment: Ok here's the minimal reproducible example I could do (created with Intellij, if that even matters): https://mega.nz/file/baIHAYKR#VrAVoJqaxaUmcXBkoT1mg9WuMgdrKZy2UQ1liXojdvk
I put everything in there... css, javafx app, controllers, fxml... and in case that's needed, just don't forget to put your vm arguments to `--module-path ./lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize only (I hope this works):

```
public void resize(SVGPath svg, double width, double height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    double originalWidthR = svg.prefWidth(-1);
    double originalHeightR = svg.prefHeight(originalWidthR);

    double scaleXr = width / originalWidthR;
    double scaleYr = height / originalHeightR;

    svg.setScaleX(scaleXr);
    svg.setScaleY(scaleYr);
}
```

And if you want to set bounds use this:

```
public void setBounds(SVGPath svg, double width, double height, double x, double y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    double originalWidthR = svg.prefWidth(-1);
    double originalHeightR = svg.prefHeight(originalWidthR);

    double scaleXr = width / originalWidthR;
    double scaleYr = height / originalHeightR;

    svg.setScaleX(scaleXr);
    svg.setScaleY(scaleYr);
    
    svg.setLayoutX((originalWidthR - width) + x);
    svg.setLayoutY((originalHeightR - height) + y);
}
```

Comment: Something went wrong while replying so I'm sorry for untidy answer

Comment: You can [edit] your answer to try and fix things.

Comment: That would totally work if the svg was only one path. But as I have here 4 different paths, it just resize them as 4 squares and gives some weird results. Example here with a 45*45 square: https://imgur.com/jCGCBl1

Comment: Understand you, try to put all of those paths into group, then do the same code above but type Group instead of SVGPath (And of course set the graphics for the button The Group).

Comment: Using a group works perfectly fine for keeping the ratio, thanks! Now I only have to figure out how to keep them in their box... the setLayoutX/Y doesn't seem to really help, I always get a small Y offset. Any idea?
Here's an example without using the setLayout methods. Both icons should be in the orange boxes https://imgur.com/a/H6cu2tf